# how to print names of files being downloaded

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that downloads all the .txt files from a website 'http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/'.

So far I have `wget -A txt -r -l 1 -nd 'http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/'`  but I'm struggling to find a way to print the name of each file to the screen (when downloading). That's the part I'm really stuck on. How would one print the names?

Thoughts?

*EDIT this is what I have done so far, but I'm trying to remove a lot of stuff like `ghcnd-inventory.txt</a></td><td align=...`*

```
wget -O-  $LINK | tr '"' '\n' | grep -e .txt | while read line; do
        echo Downloading $LINK$line ...
        wget $LINK$line
done
```

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the site?  You can do a simple get on the directory, extract the relevant file names from the HTML directory listing, and then collect the individual files you're interested in.  The code shown seems to download the files, and then discards them if they're not wanted after all.  That's expensive for multi-gigabyte files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LINK='http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/'

wget -O-  $LINK | tr '"' '\n' | grep -e .txt | grep -v align | while read line; do
        echo Downloading $LINK$line ...
        wget -nv  $LINK$line
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight optimization of Sundeep's answer:

```
LINK='http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/'
wget -q -O- $LINK | sed -E '/.*href="[^"]*\.txt".*/!d;s/.*href="([^"]*\.txt)".*/\1/' | wget -nv -i- -B$LINK
```

The `sed` command eliminates all lines not matching `href="xxx.txt"` and extracts only the `xxx.txt` part of the others. It then passes the result to another `wget` that uses it as the list of files to retrieve. The `-nv` option tells `wget` to be as less verbose as possible. It will thus print the name of the file it currently downloads but almost nothing else. Warning: this works only for this particular web site and does not descend in the sub-directories.